# Regression Reporting

Tags: regression

There are 2 significant variables in my regression and others are insignificant. How should I report the finding? Should I leave few insignificant variables out? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It would invalidate all of your results to remove the "insignificant" variables (not to mention that "insignificant" is in the eye of the beholder).  This site has much discussion on this point.